# sharedpreferences multiple activities Android Studio 2.1

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

With this below code i am assigning value to Mode_DataPath In Login Page

```
sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, MODE_PRIVATE);
editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
editor.putString("Mode_DataPath", "Some_Value");// Database Path 
editor.commit();
```

And With This Below Code Iam Getting Value in Main Activity Success Fully

```
sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, MODE_PRIVATE);
Mode_Area_Name = (sharedpreferences.getString("Mode_DataPath", ""));
```

But My Problem is  when iam click on button and  going to another activity i am getting Empty value with above Same Code Please Any Body Help me

This is already Worked For Me But When i am Upgrade To Android Studio 2.1 The Problem is Raising

Comment: Can you post the complete definition of the class?

Comment: Check whether your MyPREFERENCES is the same across in your other activity.

Comment: You could use a singleton pattern for your SharedPreferences

Comment: Even if .commit() has better thread safe, also you can try .apply() too. Maybe it solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I made some edit to your code. Try this:

```
SharedPreferences.Editor sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, 0).edit();
editor.putString("key", "value");
editor.commit();
```

in any activity across your application

```
SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, 0);
String myValue =  sharedpreferences.getString("key","NA");
```